# how to check if current user have a shop or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a one to one association with shops and user, that means each user can have one shop. What I want to do is check if current user already have a shop or not, if current user has a shop I want to show him link to his shop otherwise a button to add a shop. How can i do this in rails using the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible you would use erb syntax:

```
<% if current_user&.shop_id %>
  <%= link_to "/shop/#{current_user.shop_id}" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "/add-shop" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it gives the error undefined method `shop_id' for nil:NilClass @Sergio Belevskij

Answer (score 1):

you can use [any?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/any%3F)

```
current_user.shop.any?
```

Returns true if there are any records

Answer (score 0):

You can use [present?](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) method.

```
current_user.shop.present?
```

it returns true if there is any ActiveRecord Data available.
please also note the comment on this answer. from @obermillerk

Comment: More precisely, it returns true if the value is not nil, it can be used on pretty much any object, not just active record objects.